# Powershell code to get report of alerts trigerred in past 14 days

Tags: azure, powershell, alerts

Am trying to get report of alerts fired in past 14 days from a resource group in Azure through PowerShell, The below code is running but the output of excel is blank.

```
Get-AzAlert -TargetResourceGroup xxxxxxx | Export-Excel -Path C:\Users\name\Downloads\a.xlsx
$filterDate=(Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
```

Tried the above code, but the output of excel is blank.

Comment: try this.

$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
Get-AzAlert -TargetResourceGroup xxxxxxx |
    Where-Object { $_.Properties.TimeCreated -ge $filterDate } |
    Export-Excel -Path C:\Users\name\Downloads\a.xlsx

Comment: At line:1 char:39
+ $filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14) Get-AzAlert -TargetResourceGrou ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Get-AzAlert' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

getting the error..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, got the output successfully with this query:

```
#Get the date for last 14 days with time format
$filterDate =  (Get-Date).AddDays(-14).tostring("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt")

#Getting the alerts details with filter 14days from 30 days result
$result=Get-AzAlert -TargetResourceGroup xxxxxxxx -TimeRange '30d' | Where-Object { $_.StartDateTime -ge $filterDate }

$result | Select-Object StartDateTime, Name, MonitorCondition, Severity, TargetResource | export-csv -path C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\report.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a PowerShell report of alerts fired in the last 14 days from an Azure resource group:

***Try below script and it worked for me as follows:***

```
$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$targetresourceid = "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/newvm" //(Get-Azresource -Name <resourcename>).ResourceID
$alerts = Get-AzAlert -TargetResourceId $targetresourceid | Where-Object { $_.Properties.TimeCreated -le $filterDate }
$alerts | Export-Csv -Path "C:\<filename>.csv"
```

[image]

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

You can also obtain metrics for a particular time range by providing `-CustomTimeRange` parameter which includes starttime and endtime and clearly detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.alertsmanagement/get-azalert?view=azps-9.5.0).